# Distributing a modified OpenJDK class with a proprietary app

Tags: java, licensing, gpl, closed-source

I want to distribute a Java class I borrowed from the GPLv2'ed *OpenJDK* and modified for my own needs as a part of my proprietary application.

The header at the top of the source file states (and I've preserved the same in the modified copy):

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 1999, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
 * DO NOT ALTER OR REMOVE COPYRIGHT NOTICES OR THIS FILE HEADER.
 *
 * This code is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
 * under the terms of the GNU General Public License version 2 only, as
 * published by the Free Software Foundation.  Oracle designates this
 * particular file as subject to the "Classpath" exception as provided
 * by Oracle in the LICENSE file that accompanied this code.
 */
```

1. Given that classpath exception is effective, would it be sufficient to distribute the modified `*.java` file packed alongside the corresponding `*.class` file in a JAR archive? Am I obliged to explicitly mention that "this product uses software distributed under GPLv2" somewhere in the `THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME.txt` file?
2. Alternatively, would it be sufficient to create a GPLv2'ed (with classpath exception) Maven artifact, deploy a binary artifact together with my product, and give the link to the source artifact in the `THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME.txt` file?
3. In either of the above cases, does it make any sense to additionally include something like

   ```
   private static final String LICENSE = "This code is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License version 2 only, as published by the Free Software Foundation.";
   ```

   in the source code, so that the license clause is additionally available in the binary class file(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either of your options is a valid way of complying with the license, but from a practical standpoint the second is preferable because it allows developers to work more easily with your modified code. As to including the license string in the binary, I'm not convinced I see the point - who's going to be looking for it there?